# is it possible to use the subsystem command and define other types of commands?

Tags: c, gcc, dev-c++

I want to create a driver that can run during Boot but VStudio is too heavy, so I use Dev-C++ 6.3 a good programming program

but when using /SUBSYSTEM Dev-C++ the compiler says [Error] /SUBSYSTEM=BOOT_APPLICATION: No such file or directory

Comment: Please note that Dev-C++ is old and unmaintained, and the compiler it ships with is equally old and unmaintained.

Comment: As for your error, options starting with a slash are for the Visual Studio VC++ compiler, they're not GCC options.

Comment: And what do you mean by "driver that can run during boot"? What is the actual and underlying problem that program is supposed to solve? Why do you think a boot-time driver would solve the problem? Right now your question is really an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please [edit] it to ask about your original and underlying problem directly instead.

Comment: Lastly please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: telling the truth my name is suffering

Comment: Second the driver I am talking about is for old system that I want to modify the system!

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: third me that the \ is for VStudio, but since I am a sufferer, I put \ instead of -.

Comment: My compiler is TDM-GCC 10.3.0

Comment: Thank you to those who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!

when using -Wl it is as if you use ld.exe -Wl  Pass comma-separated  on to the linker.

so this is what I understood ld.exe --help -Wl,-subsystem, [Number or Word] : [version number]
as I didn't need a subsystem, I then put -Wl,-subsystem,0001:0

0001 = unknown subsystem; 0002 = Windows GUI; ???? = Windows CUI